# Remove empty brackets from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, regex, replace

I would like to remove the matching elements `{},` and `{}` from a JSON string.

**Input :** `"test": [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],`

**Output :** `"test": [],`

To do so, I tried :

```
var jsonConfig = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
var jsonFinal = jsonConfig.replace(/[{},]/g, ''); // Remove global
var jsonFinal = jsonConfig.replace(/[{},]/, ''); // Remove brackets

console.log(jsonFinal);
```

and many more.

How can I remove only those set of elements from my JSON without impacting the other brackets and comma?

Comment: you want do this for concrete property `test`?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this by manipulating the JSON text? Why not manipulate the actual object and then stringify it? `jsonObj.test = [];` if `test` was a direct property of `jsonObj`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do **NOT** attempt to modify JSON with string manipulation functions.
>
> **ALWAYS** parse the JSON, transform the data, and re-`stringify` to JSON.

**EDIT:** this answer addresses your comment that the `input` data object will contain other potential keys that should be present in the output.

```
// a couple of procedures to help us transform the data
const isEmptyObject = x => Object.keys(x).length === 0;
const not = x => ! x;
const comp = f => g => x => f (g (x));
const remove = f => xs => xs.filter (comp (not) (f));

// your input json
let json = '{"test": [{},{},{"x": 1}], "test2": [{},{}], "a": 1, "b": 2}';

// parsed json
let data = JSON.parse(json);

// transform data
let output = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, data, {

  // remove all empty objects from `test`
  test: remove (isEmptyObject) (data.test),

  // remove all empty objects from `test2`
  test2: remove (isEmptyObject) (data.test2),
}));

// display output
console.log(output); // '{"test":[{"x":1}],"test2":[],"a":1,"b":2}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and +1 for your answer. May I ask how to remove the brackets around `{"test":[]}` so it becomes `"test":[]` without using `output.replace(/[{}]/g, '');`

Comment: And why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because the object is nested in a more complex structure, `{
"test": [
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  "test2": [
    {},
    {}  
  ],
  "test3": [
    {},
    {}
  ]
}`

Comment: @superslinky, I've edited my answer to address this comment. Other input keys will now be present in the output.

Comment: I need to remove every `{}` and `{},` from each key but with your solution i end up in this situation : `{
  "test": [
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  {"test2": [
    {},
    {}
  ]},
  "test3": [
    {},
    {}
  ]
}`

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @superslinky I provided a final update which shows a) how to filter empty objects from multiple keys, and b) that the filter will preserve objects that are not empty.

Answer (score 2):

I like the **ES2015** answer of @naomik.
This is another alternative:

```
/**
 * Remove empty objects or arrays
 * @param  {Object, Array} obj: the object to which remove empty objects or arrays
 * @return {Any}
 */
const removeEmptyObject = (function() {
  const isNotObject = v => v === null || typeof v !== "object";
  const isEmpty = o => Object.keys(o).length === 0;

  return function(obj) {
    if (isNotObject(obj)) return obj;
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
      for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i += 1) {
        if (isNotObject(obj[i])) continue;
        if (isEmpty(obj[i])) obj.splice(i--, 1);
        else obj[i] = removeEmptyObject(obj[i]);
      }
    }
    else {
      for (let p in obj) {
        if (isNotObject(obj[p])) continue;
        if (!isEmpty(obj[p])) obj[p] = removeEmptyObject(obj[p]);
        if (isEmpty(obj[p])) delete obj[p];
      }
    }
    return obj;
  }
}());
```

Now lets test the code:

```
var json = '{"test": [{},{},{"x": 1}], "test2": [{},{}], "test3":[[],[1,2,3],[]], "a": 1, "b": 2}';
var data = JSON.parse(json); //Object
var output = removeEmptyObject(data);

console.log(output);
console.log(removeEmptyObject(9));
console.log(removeEmptyObject(null));
console.log(removeEmptyObject({}));
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for me. just had to modify it a bit. For example, your solution wont work for such case: `{a: [{a: {}}]}`. So, I've changed for loop like this: 
      ```for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i += 1) {
        if (isNotObject(obj[i])) continue;
        obj[i] = removeEmptyObject(obj[i]);        
        if (isEmpty(obj[i])) obj.splice(i--, 1);
      }```

Answer (score 1):

You should work on the actual object not the string.

If you do, you can loop through the object and check if it has any properties. If it doesn't have any, you can remove it.

```
for(var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
       //remove here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the question of whether string manipulation is the best way to tidy up JSON data, your earlier attempts would remove *all* braces and commas, because `[]` in a regexp indicates "match any of the characters contained inside these brackets".  If you were trying to treat those as literal characters, they'd need to be escaped: `\[` or `\]`

You want something like `.replace(/{},?/g,"")` (which means "match all instances of the string `{}` or the string `{},` -- the question mark makes the preceding character an optional match).

(This would, of course, remove *all* empty objects from the string, and has the potential to create invalid JSON given input like "foo: {}, bar: {}" -- so only use this if you're certain that your data will never include intentionally empty objects.)

Comment: This still has issues with JSON in the form `[{"test":{}}]`. I'm not sure if this case applies to the OP though.

Comment: True enough!   Have updated the answer with that caveat, thanks.